# How much is this in GH/s?

Tags: hashpower

I Hope i can get some help from you.

when i have `2.43 TH`, how much is this in GH/s?
I'm complete confused, cause i tried to find out, how much is this.
Can someone tell me how much GH/s this is at two decimals?

Also i was looking for Hashcalculator on web, but i dont find any calculator where i can change my hashrates to other...

I find this, but i dont know if its right.

```
1 MH/s = 1,000 kH/s
1 GH/s = 1,000 MH/s = 1,000,000 kH/s
1 TH/s = 1,000 GH/s = 1,000,000 MH/s = 1,000,000,000 kH/s
```

and how much is 2.43TH/s in GH/s with 2 decimal

Answer (score 1):

2.43 TH/s is 2430.00 GH/s. The conversion chart you have is correct.